# Voltage multiplier not working

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, ac, multimeter

Why are both the voltmeters in the circuit showing the same. The blue one should have triple the voltage. What's wrong in my circuit?[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Reference point selected went wong :)

Comment: Motu means that the bout voltmeter should have -ve terminal connected to ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "blue" voltmeter should be measuring from the point you have marked "0V" to the junction of the right most capacitor and diode.

In other words, move the minus connection of the voltmeter to the point marked "0V."